# Perl Script / MySQL query that counts existing array from mysql database query of a field

Tags: mysql, arrays, perl

Hard for me to explain but I will try.

I have a mysql table with a field called "inventory" which is an array of items.  I need to count the number of different items in this array. My problem is I have players on a game that are putting too many items into this array and it causes issues.

Here is an example:

[[["NVGoggles","Mk_48_DZ"],[3,10]],[["ItemBandage","Skin_Sniper1_DZ"],[2,34]],[["DZ_Backpack_EP1"],[1]]]

This array should count as 5 items. The number of each item doesn't matter in this case.
NVGoggles, Mk_48_DZ, ItemBandage, Skin_Sniper1_DZ, DZ_Backpack_EP1

Example of empty array:

[[[],[]],[[],[]],[[],[]]]

I need the script to:

SELECT inventory FROM `instance_deployable` where deployable_id = 16
Count the inventory array for each row.
Update the inventory for row if count is greater than 50 different items.

I'm stumped on how to count the array with either MySQL or a Perl script.

Comment: umm, how do you store the array exactly? SQL has no concept of such a type…. Are you storing it as a string?

Comment: Yes as a string.  I'm a bit out of my element here.

Comment: what's the primary key?

Comment: id is primary key.  i can post up the structure if that helps.

Comment: was there some specific way you wanted the inventory updated?  or just remove items till it is no longer more than 50?

Comment: If that's possible that would be great.  Otherwise setting inventory to [] which would be "empty" would be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use JSON 'decode_json', 'encode_json';
use List::Util 'sum';

my $limit = 50;
my $deployable_id = 16;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=test;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306','user','pass',{RaiseError=>1,AutoCommit=>1});
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select distinct inventory from inventory_deployable where deployable_id=?');
$sth->execute($deployable_id);

my @bad_inventory;
while ( my ($inventory_col) = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    my $inventory = decode_json($inventory_col);
    if ( $limit < sum map scalar @{ $_->[0] }, @$inventory ) {
        push @bad_inventory, $inventory_col;
    }
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare('update inventory_deployable set inventory=? where inventory=? and deployable_id=?');

for my $inventory_col (@bad_inventory) {
    my $inventory = decode_json($inventory_col);
    my $keep = $limit;
    for my $category (@$inventory) {
        if ( @{ $category->[0] } > $keep ) {
            splice @{ $category->[0] }, $keep;
            splice @{ $category->[1] }, $keep;
        }
        $keep -= @{ $category->[0] };
    }
    my $new_inventory_col = encode_json($inventory);
    $sth->execute($new_inventory_col, $inventory_col, $deployable_id);
}
```

Comment: Working almost perfect.

If limit is 50 it leaves 49/50 after running.  If I change limit to 51 it leaves 51/50. Hmmm